# Quiero pegar el código de popads en mi aplicación Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, publish

Estoy intentando pegar el código que genere en popads para poner anuncios en mi sitio web tengo que pegar el script pero me da el mismo error cuando chequeo

```
> Resultados de la comprobación http://instablog.iceiy.com/infinite-v4.4/ :
No pudimos encontrar el código PopAds en su sitio web. Asegúrese de que esté instalado correctamente (no se encontró ninguna etiqueta HEAD válida).
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= $activeLang->short_form; ?>">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title><?= esc($title); ?> - <?= esc($settings->site_title); ?></title>
<script type="text/javascript" data-cfasync="false">
/*<![CDATA[/* */
(function(){var t=window,f="e4f9153d1ecfa9eb604f0e9a28456780",y=[["siteId",366-902-987-508*96+5129972],["minBid",0],["popundersPerIP","0"],["delayBetween",0],["default",false],["defaultPerDay",0],["topmostLayer","auto"]],g=["d3d3LnhhZHNtYXJ0LmNvbS9qcmVhY3QucHJvZHVjdGlvbi5taW4uY3Nz","ZDExZW5xMnJ5bXkweWwuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvY29tbW9uL3NkYXJrbW9kZS1qcy5taW4uanM="],a=-1,x,u,c=function(){clearTimeout(u);a++;if(g[a]&&!(1735928063000<(new Date).getTime()&&1<a)){x=t.document.createElement("script");x.type="text/javascript";x.async=!0;var j=t.document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];x.src="https://"+atob(g[a]);x.crossOrigin="anonymous";x.onerror=c;x.onload=function(){clearTimeout(u);t[f.slice(0,16)+f.slice(0,16)]||c()};u=setTimeout(c,5E3);j.parentNode.insertBefore(x,j)}};if(!t[f]){try{Object.freeze(t[f]=y)}catch(e){}c()}})();
/*]]>/* */
</script>
</head>
```

Aquì es donde pegue el codigo ruta:
app/Views/partials/header.php

Estoy utilizando la plantilla Infinite - Blog & Magazine Script
link: https://codecanyon.net/item/infinite-blog-magazine-script/19890709

Comment: Pero... qué tiene que ver la ruta de tu proyecto con el error que nos muestras?? Te está diciendo que tu página no tiene etiqueta `<head>` válida. Dónde pusiste el script??

Comment: Ahí hice los arreglos a la publicación. Gracias!!! @Benito-B

Comment: sigo sin ver el codigo popads en tu codigo html XD

Comment: Listo. @FranciscoNuñezIALover